# Regex for combining digits

Tags: regex, vim

I have a sequence of digits like below. I want to combine digits to group of 4. Can someone give a vim regex to do that?

Input : 1234 56 7890 1234

The output should be:  1234 5678 9012 34

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two pass:

```
s/ //g
s/\(.\{4\}\)/\1 /g
```

Comment: I was just wondering, if there exist a regex that can do in one pass

Comment: I don't think there is a way to so this in one pass with a regex. I can't think of how to remove the spaces in the same pass as grouping into 4s.

Comment: @Autocracy - You CAN do it in one pass, but it's awful. I +1'ed because this is the best solution in my opinion, but for a one-pass solution, see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910133/regex-for-combining-digits/910222#910222

Comment: Hmmmm... interesting, CPU consuming, and brain damaging :)

Congrats on coming up with that. Almost an antipattern.

Answer (score 4):

I would do this in two steps:
(1) remove the blanks right of digit groups

```
:s/\(\d\+\) /\1/g
```

(2) grouping:

```
:s/\(\d\{4}\)/\1 /g
```

In case of many lines record a macro
or do these steps for an marked area.

Answer (score 4):

You *can* do it in one pass, but it looks awful:

```
:s/\(\d\) *\(\d\) *\(\d\) *\(\d\) */\1\2\3\4 /g
```

While this works, it's rather asinine. It's faster to do one of those nice two-pass solutions than to spend 2 minutes working out one Monsteregex™ that does it in one pass. Plus, the two-pass solutions are easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
:s/\(\d\)\s*\(\d\)\s*\(\d\)\s*\(\d\)\s*/\1\2\3\4 /g
```

works, but I prefers [Autocracy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910133/regex-for-combining-digits/910158#910158).